# Deriving relations for a hard sphere phase diagram

Tags: mathematical-modeling, statistical-thermodynamics, derivations, radial-distribution-function, correlation-functions

In Torquato's book "[Random Heterogeneous Materials](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-6355-3)", he has written:
$$\frac{p}{\rho kT} = 1+2^{d-1}\eta g_2 (D^{+})\tag{1}$$
where $g_2(D^+)$ is the contact value from the right-side of the radial distribution function, and $\eta$ is a dimensionless reduced density, where $d$ is the dimension, $\eta = \rho v(D)$, where $v(D)$ is the volume of a cylinder with radius $D$.

After a couple lines, he states that for hard spheres, via the Ornstein-Zernike equation, we can rewrite the above equation in terms of the direct correlation function $c(r)$ as
$$\frac{p}{\rho kT} = 1+2^{d-1}\eta [c(D^+)-c(D^-)]\tag{2}.$$

How does he reach this conclusion?

Ornstein-Zernike states:
$$h(r_{12}) = c(r_{12}) + \rho \int d\mathbf{r}_3 c(r_{13})h(r_{32})\tag{3}$$
which after a Fourier transform becomes, where $r_i$ is the position of the particle $i$, and $r_{ij}$ is the displacement vector $r_i-r_j$,
$$\hat{C} (\mathbf{k}) = \frac{\hat{H}(\mathbf{k})}{1+\rho \hat{H}(\mathbf{k})}\tag{4}$$
where, $\hat{C} = \mathcal{F}[c], \hat{H} = \mathcal{F} [h]$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform.
However, I don't see how to simplify this to the second equation he has. I would appreciate any advice you have.

Comment: +1. There's still a lot of undefined symbols or variables, maybe you can tell us what they mean?

Comment: I have added some extra definitions. hope they help @NikeDattani

Comment: That's much better. I think $r$ and $r_{ij}$ are not defined, and while $D^{\pm}$ might be deducible, it's not totally clear.

Comment: I'd like to help you but I don't have.a copy of that book. Have you seen this elsewhere too? Are there other references you can give us?

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments. Since the book doesn't seem to be readily available, it may help if you can quote the lines between equations 1 and 2.